# NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 41

Tags: objective-c, nsxmlparser

I am parsing a xml file which giving an error

NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 41

Will anyone tell me what is the reason of this error and how to solve this error.

Thank in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an `NSXMLParserAttributeHasNoValueError`. One of your attributes is missing a value.

For the future, all these are defined in the `NSXMLParserErrorDomain` document in the iOS Library.